# expressions in forvalues in Stata

Tags: for-loop, stata

I want to express the following using Stata code:

```
for(i=0;i<n;++i) {
   for(j=i+1;j<n-1;++j) {
      print i*j;
  }
}
```

The outer `for` could be:

```
forvalues i = 0/`n' {
   //rest of the code
}
```

But the inner `for` has expressions, and I do not know how to express that.

PS: I think I know how to express the same using local variables or `while`, but I would like to avoid that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code fragment demonstrates some technique. It presupposes that a local macro `n` is defined previously.

Long version:

```
local I = `n' - 1 
forval i = 0/`I' {
    local J = `I' - 1 
    local ip1 = `i' + 1 
    forval j = `ip1'/`J' {
        display `i' * `j'
    }
}
```

Shorter version:

```
forval i = 0/`= `n' - 1' {
    forval j = `=`i' + 1'/`= `n' - 2' {
        display `i' * `j'
    }
}
```

Note: the term "local variable" is just a hodgepodge of Stata terminology and your own import from somewhere else of what a variable is. In Stata terms: the beasts here are local macros and there are no variables in this code.

Note: Mata is much closer to the C-like syntax you give.

Note: You can't avoid local macros when using local macros. `forvalues` is all about using local macros to control looping.

Comment: I am sorry, I couldn't understand your notes.
Note 1) Why is the Mata syntax is important in this question? In STATA, Can we use Mata?
Note 2) I think your sentence is always true for any affirmation (p => p). Is something that I missed?
Note 3) "What leads you to adopt that incorrect spelling?"??? the STATA name?

Comment: Your code is Mata code which you can execute in Stata using `mata:`.

Comment: @Metrics is almost correct: try `print` in Mata. For the rest, the spelling is "Stata" not "STATA".

Comment: You asked how to do this without using local macros, but `forvalues` is all about using local macros to control looping.